# A question on Yuffie in Final fantasy 7

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I sadly have no more access to the original final fantasy 7, but I wondered about the following:
Yuffie steals all your materia when you go to wutai the first time. But what happens when you sell all your materia before (so you have 0 materia and she cant steal any)? Does she say anything different?

Comment: Just going to do a "no materia" run now, ill let you know how it goes or if I hit a sticking point...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question interested me so I decided to do a run through and avoid picking up any materia. Any that was forced upon me I just "trashed". To my surprise there are no safeguards on materias, I thought I was stuck when Priscilla gave me Shiva but I was able to trash summons too.

So I played through the game without any materia up to the point you get the Tiny Bronco (the earliest you can go to Wutai).

Note: I am playing PS4 version so I have the cheats for unlimited HP/MP and 3x speed, so this was much easier than it would be on the original PS1 version.

**Answer**

The scene where Yuffie steals your materia is exactly the same, everyone acts like materia was stolen even though I had none at all. Dialog is all the same as if you had had some to steal.

**Additional Information**

After completing the Yuffie side quest she gives back your materia. This is the **MP Absorb** materia that you pick up during the "hunt for Yuffie". So technically the dialog for giving back materia makes sense, as there is always at least one material for her to return.

**Strange Glitch**

During the quest to get my materia back (of lack there of), I was able to somehow get 2x **MP Plus** materia out of thin air!

I want to start by saying I dont know if this glitch is specific to the Yuffie sidequest, or if its doable elsewhere too. I also dont know if it would happen if I had materia going into the quest or not... I've never found this before. However, it happened during this experiment so I will include it as part of this answer.

Here is what happened to get the glitch to happen...

1. My team before Yuffie stole materia was Cloud, Vincent and Yuffie (in that order)
2. Barret joined after Yuffie ran off and I replaced him with Cid using PHS
3. I played side quest until I got MP Absorb from chest which Yuffie immediately steals
4. This prompted me to check my materia list. Empty. So I went to "Exchange" to check if anyone had materia equiped
5. Nobody did, but to my surprise the cursor was defaulted to an invisible character. You couldnt see any slots or materia but you could navigate the cursor to all 16 slots (8 weapon and 8 armor). They all said "MP Plus"
6. I tried pressing triangle to remove the materia this worked on the first 2 weapon slots only. The rest just did nothing
7. This gave me 2 MP Plus materia in my inventory that I didnt have before

My best guess at how this glitch was possible...

1. I have config set to cursor = memory
2. Before Yuffie left my party I had checked her on the exchange. So cursor was still on her slot when I went back in to exchange later
3. The game possibly defaults to MP Plus when it doesnt know what to do in this situation
4. I expect the reason why I could only remove 2 materia was because Yuffie was previous equiped with a 2-slot weapon and a 0-slot armor, and the game thought that invisible person was Yuffie so her weapon/armor logic was applied

Overall that was a lot longer answer than I was expecting from this experiment but a very interesting outcome none the less.

Answer (score 0):

Without having played this particular circumstance myself (though I have played the original FF7 many times), I can't say for certain. However; my bet would be **no.**

The reasons being that firstly; there is no evidence of this in any wikis that I have been able to find about this particular event. Instead, there is a clarification that she has an [upper limit of 48 Materia that she can steal](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Wutai_Village#Retrieving_stolen_Materia). Meaning if you have more than 48 Materia equipped or loose in your inventory, she won't leave the party completely broke.

Additionally, not only is their a limit, but also a priority. The main priority to the Materia she steals are all one-off Materia you find; Summons, Master Command and Magic, MP All, etc.

So all in all, whether you have them all or not, a lot of these Materia you *do* have would be far too valuable to even decide to sell (if you even *can* sell it all?), since you won't be able to get them back; so it's likely the dev's never even accounted for it. There's a potential chance that you may not even be able to reach Wutai or trigger this event without any Materia, or even potentially break the game.